# passing variables from multiple workbooks to one workbook

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am using Visual basic from excel to open a different workbook and pass some things from one to another. I have the second file opening fine however I cant get the second file to read the things I need.

```
Sub createExcel()
Cells(1, 1).Text = "va02"
Dim objExcel
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
    End Sub
```

this is my code to open the second application. I have 2 variables in 2 cells in the first workbook. How would one go about getting the variables. the problem i have encountered is; the second workbook can be called from any file, in any folder.

i would try
    variable = Workbooks(firstWorkbook.xlsm).worksheets(sheet1)...
however the worksheets dont have the same names either. please help

thanks

Comment: You're talking about 2 variables in 2 cells, but the only variables I'm seeing are `objExcel`, `objWorkbook`, and `filepath`, with only `objExcel` being actually declared. Stick `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, declare every variable you're using. Now, I've no idea what you're asking. If you don't know the name of the worksheet, its codename, index, or anything, then you can't grab a reference to any specific sheet. Use explicit references: `Cells(1,1)` is implicitly referring to whatever worksheet is currently active, which is very error-prone.

Comment: Why do you open two different Excel instances? Can’t you open the second workbook in the same Excel instance that opened the first workbook?

Comment: @Mat'sMug, the code that i showed is only the code to open the other workbook. The first workbook will get its own filepath and file name and insert them into 2 cells on sheet1 then open WB 2. WB2 will then reach into WB1 and read those 2 cells and insert those into variables in WB2. my question is, how do i reach from WB2 into WB1 to read cells

Comment: Maybe reading [mcve] will help you structure things more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is in Workbook1, and opens Workbook2. So it's Workbook1 that does everything - so " I cant get the second file to read the things I need" is not meaningful.

```
  Sub Demo(filepath as string)
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).cells(1,1).text = "This is written by initial Workook"      
  Dim Wb as Workbook
  Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(filepath)
  Wb.Sheets(1).cells(1,2) = "So is this, even though it's in a different workbook"
  End Sub
```

Comment: That did exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!